# Cannot fetch the Google Calendar name through API using Calendar ID

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer, google-calendar-api

I need to fetch the calendar Name from the calendar ID. I've given the correct Google Calendar ID and sent it through api to fetch the calendar details and get the calendar name.

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com

    Method type: GET
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: Bearer <latest access_token>
```

I've checked it with Google Calendar API online, it is working fine. But when i pass it through postman or in my java code, the following json is recieved.

```
    {
      "error": {
        "errors": [
          {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Not Found"
          }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
      }
    }
```

This error occurs only when i give the default calendar ID's like `en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com(Holidays in India)`

Comment: The corect call for calendarlist is https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList  which will show the calendars you have installed in your calendar list.    You cant pass it a calendar.   What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to fetch the calendar name from the calendar ID en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com

Comment: Please edit your question and include a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the information about a calendar you should use

> [Calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) Returns metadata for a calendar.

Request (note access token):

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com?access_token=youraccesstoken

Response

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"fBXC91rAg76NkSpaCdEoUEir1ww/pR1e1Z3gR0361TBF8mRGGxGD_VM\"",
 "id": "en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
 "summary": "Holidays in India",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen"
}
```

This call requires that you be authenticated yes even for a public calendar.

Calendar list will only work if the user who has authenticated has added this calendar to there calendar list.

[Calendarlist.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get)

request

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com?access_token=youraccesstoken

Response

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
 "etag": "\"1442929251602000\"",
 "id": "en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
 "summary": "Holidays in Denmark",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "colorId": "11",
 "backgroundColor": "#fbe983",
 "foregroundColor": "#000000",
 "selected": true,
 "accessRole": "reader",
 "defaultReminders": []
}
```

> Authorization
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes (read more about authentication and authorization).
>
> Scope
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Note: My calendars is a list of calendars that the user in question has created.   Other calendars is a list of calendars that was shared with the user.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But still I get the same error. Is there any possibility that we can't access the 'Other Calendars' section which has the 'Holidays in India', 'Holidays in United States', etc. And can we give the access_token in the Authorization header instead of giving it in url itself?

Comment: Make sure you are authenticated with the correct scope?    You should also be able to do Authorization Bearer accessToken as the header it will work.

Comment: yes I've authenticated with correct scope and included latest access_token. The result is displayed for other calendars listed under 'My Calendars' section in Google Calendar, but error occurs in 'Other Calendars' section

Comment: So we can't edit or access the 'Other Calendars' using api. Can we?

Comment: Other calendars are calendars that are owned by other people.  If the owner gave you permission to write to it then yes you can change it.   But you can not edit the holiday calendars google has not given you permission to do that.

Comment: "But you can not edit the holiday calendars google has not given you permission to do that"- This is what I was asking. Thanks alot!

Comment: No your question is about fetching the name from a google calendar you didn't say anything about changing it.

Comment: Yes if we cannot edit the holiday calendars, we can't fetch it through api right?

Comment: Consider them Read only.  You can do any read operation on them.

Comment: I could read them during CalendarList.list (while listing all calendars) option but i couldn't read it during CalendarList.get or Calendar.get (while listing particular calendar using their ID).

Comment: When you call CalendarList.list just add the parameter "minAccessRole" and set it to "owner". That way you only get back the calendarList you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Convert # to %23.
The URL removes # and after.

Refer to this [link](https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Content/SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_URLEncoding.html).